# Python re.split() vs split()

Tags: python, regex

In my quests of optimization, I discovered that that built-in split() method is about 40% faster that the re.split() equivalent.

A dummy benchmark (easily copy-pasteable):

```
import re, time, random 

def random_string(_len):
    letters = "ABC"
    return "".join([letters[random.randint(0,len(letters)-1)] for i in range(_len) ])

r = random_string(2000000)
pattern = re.compile(r"A")

start = time.time()
pattern.split(r)
print "with re.split : ", time.time() - start

start = time.time()
r.split("A")
print "with built-in split : ", time.time() - start
```

Why this difference?

Comment: Why not?  Please don't say "curiosity".  What problem do you have that's solved by asking us to read the implementation of `re` and `str` and comment on the differences.  Perhaps you could read the implementations, comment on the differences, and ask **specific** questions.

Comment: I actually expect more than %40 speed increase. Simple is faster.

Comment: I thought it was obvious (?) that split() uses some kind of regular expressions, but it does not...

Comment: @hymloth You are confusing Python with Java then (which is the only language I know that uses regex in `String.split()`)

Comment: @NullUserException: Perl's `split()` function also uses regular expressions.

Comment: @hymloth _time.clock()_ On Unix, return the current processor time as a floating point number expressed in seconds. The precision, and in fact the very definition of the meaning of “processor time”, depends on that of the C function of the same name, but **in any case, this is the function to use for benchmarking Python or timing algorithms.** (http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.clock)

Comment: @Sven Is there anything in Perl that *doesn't* use regexes?

Comment: @eyquem: The module to be used for benchmarking Python is `timeit`.  Using `time.clock()` is better than `time.time()`, but still has problems that are solved in the `timeit` module.  (One example is that `timeit` turns the garbage collector off while timing.)

Comment: @Sven Marnach I agree with you: _timeit_ has more advanced interesting features than *clock*. But I don't agree with the fact that it **IS** the module to use: the description of *clock* expresses that this function is usable for benchmarks and timings, without even saying that it is preferable to use *timeit* ; and for simple measures of times  concerning executions having a neat difference, *clock* is plenty sufficient. Before I understood that, I was wearing myself out using *timeit*, until I benchmarked *timeit* an *clock* and observed that *timeit* wasn't useful for my limmited needs.

Comment: @hymloth Use **"".join(random.choice(letters) for i in xrange(_len))** instead ( xrange if Python 2.x instead of range)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`re.split` is **expected** to be slower, as the usage of regular expressions incurs some overhead.

Of course if you are splitting on a **constant** string, there is no point in using `re.split()`.

Comment: @duhaime Because regular expressions are designed for the case where a simple constant string match is not enough. If you do not need that extra power, then it makes sense to use the regular built in split()

Comment: Ah, interesting, I didn't know that! Thanks for following up @AlexSpurling

Answer (score 10):

When in doubt, [check the source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch#JXQl-_ahfYA/trunk/Source/third_party/python-2.7/Objects/stringlib/split.h&type=cs). You can see that Python `s.split()` is optimized for whitespace and inlined. But `s.split()` is for fixed delimiters only.

For the speed tradeoff, a [re.split](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) regular expression based split is far more flexible.

```
>>> re.split(':+',"One:two::t h r e e:::fourth field")
['One', 'two', 't h r e e', 'fourth field']
>>> "One:two::t h r e e:::fourth field".split(':')
['One', 'two', '', 't h r e e', '', '', 'fourth field']
# would require an addition step to find the empty fields...
>>> re.split('[:\d]+',"One:two:2:t h r e e:3::fourth field")
['One', 'two', 't h r e e', 'fourth field']
# try that without a regex split in an understandable way...
```

That `re.split()` is *only* 29% slower (or that `s.split()` is only 40% faster) is what should be amazing.

Answer (score 4):

Running a regular expression means that you are running a state machine for each character.
Doing a split with a constant string means that you are just searching for the string.
The second is a much less complicated procedure.

Comment: @eyquem That does search without use of a state machine.