# Faster way to remove stop words in Python

Tags: python, regex, stop-words

I am trying to remove stopwords from a string of text:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
text = 'hello bye the the hi'
text = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if word not in (stopwords.words('english'))])
```

I am processing 6 mil of such strings so speed is important.  Profiling my code, the slowest part is the lines above, is there a better way to do this?  I'm thinking of using something like regex's `re.sub` but I don't know how to write the pattern for a set of words.  Can someone give me a hand and I'm also happy to hear other possibly faster methods.

Note:  I tried someone's suggest of wrapping `stopwords.words('english')` with `set()` but that made no difference.

Thank you.

Comment: How large is `stopwords.words('english')`?

Comment: @SteveBarnes A list of 127 words

Comment: did you wrap it inside list comprehension or outside? try add stw_set = set(stopwords.words('english')) and use this object instead

Comment: @alko I thought I wrapped it outside and had no effect, but I just tried it again and my code is running at least 10x faster now!!!

Comment: Are you processing the text line by line or all together?

Comment: @glasslion line by line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopword removal with NLTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130512/stopword-removal-with-nltk)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Try caching the stopwords object, as shown below. Constructing this each time you call the function seems to be the bottleneck.

```
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords

    cachedStopWords = stopwords.words("english")

    def testFuncOld():
        text = 'hello bye the the hi'
        text = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if word not in stopwords.words("english")])

    def testFuncNew():
        text = 'hello bye the the hi'
        text = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if word not in cachedStopWords])

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        for i in xrange(10000):
            testFuncOld()
            testFuncNew()
```

I ran this through the profiler: **python -m cProfile -s cumulative test.py**. The relevant lines are posted below.

nCalls   Cumulative Time

10000    7.723    words.py:7(testFuncOld)

10000    0.140    words.py:11(testFuncNew)

So, caching the stopwords instance gives a ~70x speedup.

Comment: Agreed.  The performance boosts comes from caching the stopwords, not really in creating a `set`.

Comment: Certainly you get a dramatic boost from not having to read the list from disk every time, because that's the most time-consuming operation. But if you now turn your "cached" list into a set (just once, of course), you'll get another boost.

Comment: can anyone tell me if this supports japanese?

Comment: it gives me this UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
 text=' '.join([word for word in text.split() if word not in stop_words]) please Salomone provide me solution to this

Answer (score 31):

Sorry for late reply.
Would prove useful for new users.

- Create a dictionary of stopwords using collections library
- Use that dictionary for very fast search (time = O(1)) rather than doing it on list (time = O(stopwords))

  ```
  from collections import Counter
  stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
  stopwords_dict = Counter(stop_words)
  text = ' '.join([word for word in text.split() if word not in stopwords_dict])
  ```

Comment: This does indeed speed things up considerably even in comparison to regexp based approach.

Comment: This was indeed a great answer and I wish this was more up there. It's incredible how fast this was when removing words from text from a list of 20k itens. Regular way took more than 1 hour, while using Counter took 20 seconds.

Comment: Can you explain how  'Counter'  speeds up the process? @Gulshan Jangid

Comment: well the main reason for the above code being fast is that we are searching in a dictionary which is basically a hashmap. And in hashmap the search time is O(1). Other than that Counter is part of collections library and library is written in C, and since C is way faster than python therefore Counter is faster than similar code written in python

Comment: Just tested this and it's in average 3x faster than the regexp approach. A simple yet creative solution, the current best by far.

Comment: Using this (`collections.Counter(stopwords.words('english')`) cant be faster than using `set(stopwords.words('english'))` I believe. The collections.Counter method only unnecessarily uses more memory.

Answer (score 25):

Use a regexp to remove all words which do not match:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('english')) + r')\b\s*')
text = pattern.sub('', text)
```

This will probably be *way* faster than looping yourself, especially for large input strings.

If the last word in the text gets deleted by this, you may have trailing whitespace.  I propose to handle this separately.

Comment: Any idea what the complexity of this would be?  If w = number of words in my text and s = number of words in the stop list, I think looping would be on the order of `w log s`.  In this case, w is approx s so it's `w log w`.  Wouldn't grep be slower since it (roughly) has to match character by character?

Comment: Actually I think the complexities in the meaning of O(…) are the same.  Both are `O(w log s)`, yes.  **BUT** regexps are implemented on a much lower level and optimized heavily.  Already the splitting of words will lead to copying everything, creating a list of strings, and the list itself, all that takes precious time.

Comment: This approach is *much* faster than splitting lines, word tokenizing, then checking each word in a stopwords set. Particularly for larger text inputs

Answer (score 7):

First, you're creating stop words for each string. Create it once. Set would be great here indeed.

```
forbidden_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
```

Later, get rid of `[]` inside `join`. Use generator instead.

Replace

```
' '.join([x for x in ['a', 'b', 'c']])
```

with

```
' '.join(x for x in ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Next thing to deal with would be to make `.split()` yield values instead of returning an array. <s>I believe `regex` would be good replacement here.</s> See [thist hread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501609/python-re-split-vs-split/7501659#7501659) for why `s.split()` is actually fast.

Lastly, do such a job in parallel (removing stop words in 6m strings). That is a whole different topic.

Comment: I doubt using regexp gonna be an improvement, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501609/python-re-split-vs-split/7501659#7501659

Comment: Found it just now as well. :)

Comment: Thanks.  The `set` made at least an 8x improvement to speed.  Why does using a generator help?  RAM isn't an issue for me because each piece of text is quite small, about 100-200 words.

Comment: Actually, I've seen `join` perform better with a list comprehension than the equivalent generator expression.

Comment: Set difference seems to work too
`clean_text = set(text.lower().split()) - set(stopwords.words('english'))`

Answer (score 2):

Try using this by avoid looping and instead using regex to remove stopwords:

```
import re
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

cachedStopWords = stopwords.words("english")
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(cachedStopwords) + r')\b\s*')
text = pattern.sub('', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just a regular dict seems to be the fastest solution by far.
Surpassing even the Counter solution by about 10%

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords_dict = {word: 1 for word in stopwords.words("english")}
text = 'hello bye the the hi'
text = " ".join([word for word in text.split() if word not in stopwords_dict])
```

Tested using the cProfile profiler

You can find the test code used here:
https://gist.github.com/maxandron/3c276924242e7d29d9cf980da0a8a682

EDIT:

On top of that if we replace the list comprehension with a loop we get another 20% increase in performance

```py
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords_dict = {word: 1 for word in stopwords.words("english")}
text = 'hello bye the the hi'

new = ""
for word in text.split():
    if word not in stopwords_dict:
        new += word
text = new
```