# Extract non-content English language words string - python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, wordnet

I am working on Python script in which I want to remove the common english words like "the","an","and","for" and many more from a String. Currently what I have done is I have made a local list of all such words and I just call `remove()` to remove them from the string. But I want here some pythonish way to achieve this. Have read about nltk and wordnet but totally clueless about that's what I should use and how to use it.

**Edit**

Well I don't understand why marked as duplicate as my question does not in any way mean that I know about Stop words and now I just want to know how to use it.....the question is about what I can use in my scenario and answer to that was stop words...but when I posted this question I din't know anything about stop words.

Comment: Look for "stop word removal"... and your basic approach is not that wrong...

Comment: Stop word might be useful in my scenario ...would be searching on it now ...thnx...got any link to stop words tutorial.>?

Comment: No tutorial sorry... but what your are doing is correct. Just get a long list of stop words and then use the regular expressions module to replace stop words by empty strings.

Comment: ok got it thnx...the way it is done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560498/faster-way-to-remove-stop-words-in-python) by Alfe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that what I was looking for is this:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
my_stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
```

Now I can remove or replace the words from my list/string where I find the match in my_stop_words which is a list.

For this to work I had to download the NLTK for python and the using its downloader I downloaded stopwords package.

It also contains many other packages which can be used in different situations for NLP like `words,brown,wordnet etc.`

Answer (score 2):

Do this.

```
vocabular = set (english_dictionary)
unique_words = [word for word in source_text.split() if word not in vocabular]
```

It is simple and efficient as can be. If you don't need positions of unique words, make them `set` too! Operator `in` is extremely fast on sets (and slow on lists and other containers)

Comment: Do i need to import any package for this to work..?

Comment: None. `set` is a built-in container that achieves fast searching of objects by not storing thier relative positions. The second line is a plain basic Python "list comprehension" operator.

Comment: what abt english_dictionary ..? is that supposed to be my list of ignore words..?

Comment: yes, it is. It can be any collection - a list,a tuple, an open file with one word per row...

Comment: Ok...that will be useful when I get the list of words....currently I am using long local list for that in my code....but I wanted something which exist already in python something like `stopwords` from `nltk.corpus` module... but your answer can help me making it fast as have read on many blogs that using set instead of list makes execution faster....

Comment: If it is a list it can be turned to set. However, converting a whole dictionary to set will take some time, so you may think of storing ready `set` in file between runs.

Answer (score 0):

this will also work:

```
yourString = "an elevator is made for five people and it's fast"
wordsToRemove = ["the ", "an ", "and ", "for "]

for word in wordsToRemove:
    yourString = yourString .replace(word, "")
```

Comment: Yes that works but that's what I want to avoid doing as I dont want to take my local list as it should contain all the common english words....if it was for 4-5 words then this way seemed correct...I will be doing it using nltk,corpus and stop words list that it offers