# Count Words in Python

Tags: python, list, scikit-learn

I have a list of strings in python.

`list = [ "Sentence1. Sentence2...", "Sentence1. Sentence2...",...]`

I want to remove stop words and count occurrence of each word of all different strings combined. Is there a simple way to do it?

I am currently thinking of using CountVectorizer() from scikit and than iterating for each word and combining the results

Comment: What are stop words? So you want to concatenate to one long string and then count occurrences, is that correct?

Comment: An example of the desired output would be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560498/faster-way-to-remove-stop-words-in-python

Comment: @wouter Basically you can think I have bunch of documents and I want to count how many times a word occurs across the document.

Comment: If you use tf-idf then you don't need to remove stop words

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind installing a new python library, I suggest you use [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html). 
The first tutorial does exactly what you ask:

```
# remove common words and tokenize
stoplist = set('for a of the and to in'.split())
texts = [[word for word in document.lower().split() if word not in stoplist]
         for document in documents]
```

You will then need to create the dictionary for your corpus of document and create the bag-of-words.

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
dictionary.save('/tmp/deerwester.dict') # store the dictionary, for future 
print(dictionary)
```

You can weight the result using tf-idf and stuff and do LDA quite easily after.

Have a look at the tutorial 1 [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html)

Comment: That seems helpful, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've failed to thoroughly explain what you have in mind, but this may be what you're looking for:

```
counts = collections.Counter(' '.join(your_list).split())
```

Comment: Does your code join the different strings in list by string?

Comment: Yes, all the strings are joined then split by whitespace.