# How to replace random elements of a list with a unique symbol?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newbie to python programming. I have two lists, the first list containing stopwords while the other containing the text document. I want to replace the stop words in the text document with "/".  Is there anyone that could help?

I have used the replace function, it was giving an error

```
text = "This is an example showing off word filtration"
stop = `set`(stopwords.words("english"))
text = nltk.word_tokenize(document)

`for` word in stop:
    text = text.replace(stop, "/")
`print`(text)
```

It should output
"/ / / example showing / word filtration"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a **[list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)**:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import stopwords
>>> from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize  
>>> stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
>>> text = "This is an example showing off word filtration"
>>> text_tokens = word_tokenize(text) 
>>> replaced_text_words = ["/" if word.lower() in stop_words else word for word in text_tokens]
>>> replaced_text_words
['/', '/', '/', 'example', 'showing', '/', 'word', 'filtration']
>>> replaced_sentence = " ".join(replaced_text_words)
>>> replaced_sentence
/ / / example showing / word filtration
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a regex pattern?

Your code could then look like this:

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk

text = "This is an example showing off word filtration"
text = text.lower()


import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + r'|'.join(stopwords.words('english')) + r')\b\s*')
text = pattern.sub('/ ', text)
```

In relation to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560498/faster-way-to-remove-stop-words-in-python).

Comment: `This` is a stop word it is just not matching with your regex because it is not completely lowercase i.e. the stopwords corpus only contains lowercase words.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks a lot! I updated the code above.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `word` not `stop` in your replace function.

```
for word in stop:
    text = text.replace(word, "/")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
' '/join([item if item.lower() not in stop else "/" for item in text ])
```